# How to use Array Buffers to send JSON data from Web Workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm confused as to how to send JSON data back from a webworker to the main thread via an Array Buffer.

suppose:

```
data = {"key":"value"}

worker.postMessage(data, buffers);
```

what exactly am I supposed to put in for buffers?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean to send it "via" an array buffer, and why you want to do that?.

Comment: please see here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/ and here http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast

Comment: You have an JSON object in a web worker, and would like to transfer (not copy) it to the main thread?

Comment: yes exactly, i'm not sure of the exact argument in the postMessage()

Comment: I suspect that some copying may be unavoidable: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable you can only transfer ArrayBuffer and MessagePort objects. You could potentially "pack" a JSON object into an ArrayBuffer, using something like https://github.com/theangryangel/jspack-arraybuffer, but I suspect it'll be more efficient to just copy the JSON object between the threads, rather than copy/pack it into an ArrayBuffer to then transfer.

Answer (score 1):

[`.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) accepts a message identifier and the message data like this:

```
var message_data = {'key':'val'};
worker.postMessage('my_message', message_data);
```

`message identifier` in a sense signifies the type of message or event sent, then the data are the actual message data or parameters, which can include any [JS transferable type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) (including Typed Arrays)